# UIAlertView button text changing

Tags: swift, button, uialertview, rename

After choosing line from side menu, I'm calling `alertView` (for iOS7) with this code:

```
var choiceAlert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
choiceAlert.title = "Direction"
choiceAlert.message = "Select a direction for no. \(lineNmb)."
choiceAlert.addButtonWithTitle(dirA)
choiceAlert.addButtonWithTitle(dirB)
choiceAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
choiceAlert.delegate = self
choiceAlert.tag = 3
choiceAlert.show()
```

When I'm calling it for the first time, everything is ok (it's show like I want it), but when I choose new line from side menu, `lineNmb` is changed, but button text stays same from first calling.

For example, first time it will show:

[image: First atempt]

and then for the new chose I'm getting this (buttons stays with same name):

[image: Second atempt]

were I should have this (example with iOS8 and UIAlertController where everything works great):

[image: Shoud be]

If I put `println(dirA)` in front the `choiceAlert.addButtonWithTitle(dirA)`, I can se that the value of `dirA` is changed, and variable gets new text, but it is not changed inside `alertView`. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by calling `UIAlertView` in this way:

```
var choiceAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Direction", message: "Select a direction for no. \(lineNmb).", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", otherButtonTitles: dirA,dirB)
choiceAlert.delegate = self
choiceAlert.tag = 3
choiceAlert.show()
```